# How to track performance Tracking object using JavaScript within Adobe Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to get all the resources of a page using performance timing API. The problem I'm facing is, if I run below code in the console (after the page is loaded) then I'm getting more number of resources.

Ex: this is what I see I try to see in the console.

```
performance.getEntriesByType("resource")
(31)
```

But If use this line in Adobe DTM, I'm not see 31 values in the array but less.
I understand it's because the page is not fully loaded, so we can't get all the resources at the time of execution of this code.

But what would be best approach in this scenario?

I see some thoughts on this here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2372015

but even if I want to keep all these values in a cookie/local storage and then grab it on the next page, I will get the less number of resources on the next page (for the previous page). What could be the best approach to handle this type of scenarios?

Comment: on page load store relevant info in a cookie or localStorage and then send it through on the next page view (similar to how ActivityMap works). The downside is you may miss some data from last page of visit (which may still show up if visitor comes back) but it's more accurate.

Comment: @CrayonViolent yes, that's what I'm trying to do, but at the time of exection of the line of code performance.getEntriesByType("resource"), there are only few resources available, once the page gets loaded then the number of resources/assets are more (we can check this in console)

Comment: Okay, well it sounds like you are executing your code before the page is loaded.  _On page load_, execute your code, e.g. `window.addEventListener("load", function(){ /* your code here */ });` alternatively, DTM Page Load Rules let you specify to execute on page load (Onload)